# Spock JUnit testing: NullPointer cannot invoke method persist() on null object

Tags: spring, spock

Im trying to do some unit testing on my SpringBootApplication. When i attempt to test the class "UserRepository" the it keeps telling me that its null. Im not sure whats going on.

```
Running com.bestech.spec.SpockTestSpec
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.047 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.bestech.spec.SpockTestSpec
find by email(com.bestech.spec.SpockTestSpec)  Time elapsed: 0.047 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method persist() on null object
    at com.bestech.spec.SpockTestSpec.find by email(SpockTestSpec.groovy:28)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  SpockTestSpec.find by email:28 NullPointer Cannot invoke method persist() on n...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Here is my test class

```
@DataJpaTest
class SpockTestSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager em 

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository

    def "find by email"() {
        given: "a user"
        User user = new User("Admin","9999","admin@admin.com")
        em.persist(user)
        em.flush()
        when:"that user is then found by email"
        User found = userRepository.findByEmail(user.email)
        then: "found equals user"
        found == user
    }
}
```

here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bestech</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test only dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spock -->
        <dependency> <!-- enables mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces) -->
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- enables mocking of classes without default constructor (together with 
                CGLIB) -->
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-groovy-2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.4</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Optional -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <artifactId>praze</artifactId>
</project>
```

Im not sure exactly why its telling me userRepository is null, any help is appreciated. This is my first time using spock

Comment: I think you have `NullPointerException` in this line `em.persist(user)`.

Comment: Which version of spock spring are you using? Please make sure that it is 1.1, earlier versions do not support the spring boot annotations.